# Can I have a round box shadow on a div of 0 width and height

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I am trying to create circular shapes with blurred edges. 
I was having success doing this by creating a div with 50% border-radius and then applying a box shadow. 
However, I am creating these shapes randomly with various box shadow settings and when the box shadows blur is very spread out, the color in the center is different from the div and a hard border appears. 
I tried setting the div to 0px width and height but then the rounded shape of the box shadow disappeared and it appeared square.

Is there a way to keep the round box shadow with a div of 0 width and height? or another method I should be using to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `radial-gradient` to have a similar effect:

```css
.box {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:radial-gradient(farthest-side,red ,transparent );
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

That you can combine with a blur filter to increase the shadow effect:

```css
.box {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:radial-gradient(farthest-side,red ,transparent );
 filter:blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: I want my circles to also be able to have a harder edge than what the radial-gradient would allow. BUT using just the blur filter by itself is giving me exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!!